# How to average a form over group action to make it satisfy certain condition?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, group-actions

The following is the concrete lemma

> Suppose $X$ is a vector field with no zeros and it's generated by a group action with no fixed points. Then there exists a 1-form $\omega$ such that 
>   $$ \iota_{X} \omega=1$$
>   and 
>   $$\iota_{X} d\omega=0$$

We can choose any $\omega$ satisfy the first condition since $X$ has no zeros. However, to see the second one, the text said the following

> average the form over group action then we can obtain an invariant such form

I found this explanation really unclear and confusing. What does it mean to average the form over group action without  changing its first condition? how does this relate to the second condition?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: I think representation theory and multilinear least squares optimization is the way to go here. But I am no algebraist so I am not sure.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the group action generating a vector field? Of course in the case of a $1$-dimensional Lie group, say whose Lie algebra has generator $E$, we should define (for a left action) $X_p := \frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t = 0} [\exp(t E) \cdot p]$, and changing the generator just scales $X$ by an overall constant. For a general group do you mean that there is a $1$-parameter subgroup for which $X$ can be realized this way?

Comment: In any case the averaging operation is just $A : \omega \mapsto \int_G L_g^* \omega \,dg$, where $L_g : M \to M$ is just the map given by the action of $g \in G$ and $dg$ is the unique left-invariant volume form on $G$ normalized so that $\int_G \,dg = 1$. In particular this definition requires that $G$ is compact. It follows straightforwardly from definitions that if $\iota_X \omega = 1$ then $\iota_X A(\omega) = 1$, that is, averaging a $1$-form that satisfies the first condition yields a $1$-form that still satisfies the condition.

Comment: In any case, if you can clarify the issue in my first comment, I'm happy to write up an answer that addresses your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In this case the group action is a circle action on symplectic manifold which is also Hamiltonian and the Hamiltonian action is the integral of the Hamiltonian vector field. Generally, the vector field is given by the infinitesmal action.Suppose $\tau : G \rightarrow \operatorname{Diff}(M)$ is the group action map, the "differential" of this map is $d \tau : \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}(M), \quad X \mapsto X_{M}$, where $X_{M}(m)=\left.\frac{d}{d t}\right|_{t=0} \tau(\exp (t X))(m)$ is the vector field that generates this group action. @Travis

Comment: @Travis I wonder how the averaging process realize the second condition.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments it is specified that the acting group $G$ is the circle group.

The operation of "averaging over the group action" is just the map $$A : \omega \mapsto \int_G L_g^*\omega \,dg,$$ where for any $g \in G$ the map $L_g : M \to M$ is the action of $g$, namely, $p \mapsto g \cdot p$ and $dg$ is the unique $G$-invariant $1$-form on $G$ that satisfies $\int_G dg = 1$. Unwinding definitions then shows that if $\omega$ satisfies the condition $\omega(X) = 1$ then $(A(\omega))(X) = 1$, too, that is, the averaging operation preserves the first property.

Cartan's Magic Formula asserts that 
$$\mathcal L_X \omega = \iota_X d\omega + d(\iota_X \omega) .$$ Thus, to prove that an already-averaged $1$-form $\omega$ satisfies $\iota_X d\omega = 0$, it's enough to show that $\mathcal L_X \omega = 0$, and this again amounts to unwinding definitions.